# Does alternate row color works only for table or for any other tag Ex. Div

Tags: html, css

I have created rows without using a table since it was not cooperating with my Handlebars template and now want to have zebra stripe CSS, I want to know if that css property can work on everything or not. Thanks

Comment: Please post your created code.

Comment: @Deep Patel did it answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessary you can still use `div` to do the same job, something like below:

```css
.box:nth-child(odd) {
    background: blue;
}
.box:nth-child(even) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">First row</div>
<div class="box">second row</div>
<div class="box">third row</div>
<div class="box">fourth row</div>
```